# How to debug pipes stuck at an attempt at transferring data?

Tags: linux, debugging, pipe, deadlock, strace

Consider the following situation where one program is trying to write to its stdout, which is piped to another program's stdin:

```
[19:40:11]  d33tah@server:(0) > sudo ls /proc/83292/fd -l
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 0 -> 'pipe:[2022916853]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 1 -> 'pipe:[2022916854]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 2 -> 'pipe:[2022916855]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 3 -> 'socket:[2022967532]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 4 -> 'socket:[2022967533]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 5 -> 'socket:[2022970508]'
[19:40:12]  d33tah@server:(0) > sudo ls /proc/83293/fd -l
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 0 -> 'pipe:[2022916854]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 1 -> 'pipe:[2022916857]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  9 18:49 2 -> 'pipe:[2022916858]'
[19:40:14]  d33tah@server:(0) > sudo strace -p 83292     
strace: Process 83292 attached
write(2, " ", 1
^Cstrace: Process 83292 detached
 <detached ...>
[19:40:17]  d33tah@server:(0) > sudo strace -p 83293
strace: Process 83293 attached
read(0, 
^Cstrace: Process 83293 detached
 <detached ...>
```

This happens after a few megabytes of data were succesfully transferred this way. I ruled out filesystem-related problems. Kernel logs display no information. How can I debug this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, it wasn't stdout that was clogged - it was stderr. This was because I was not reading from stderr and at a specific point, I run out of buffer memory. The solution was to inspect why the program is writing so much stderr and limit its output. Given that it was `curl`, the solution was to add `--silent`.